# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/OldFileFormatException when editing a .doc file (WORD) with java?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I try to edit a .doc file (*WORD*) with java. I used the Apache POI library, but the results are negatives. I have a previously document (a template), and i want to replace a specific word. (e.g. that i can replace "name" with a String whatever i want).

Here a example of the internet that i try to use:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.CharacterRun;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class Prueba {
     public void searchAndReplace(String inputFilename,
                                 String outputFilename,
                                 HashMap<String, String> replacements) {        
        File inputFile = null;
        File outputFile = null;
        FileInputStream fileIStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOStream = null;
        BufferedInputStream bufIStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufOStream = null;
        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = null;
        HWPFDocument document = null;
        Range docRange = null;
        Paragraph paragraph = null;
        CharacterRun charRun = null;
        Set<String> keySet = null;
        Iterator<String> keySetIterator = null;
        int numParagraphs = 0;
        int numCharRuns = 0;
        String text = null;
        String key = null;
        String value = null;

        try {
            inputFile = new File(inputFilename);
            fileIStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            bufIStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileIStream);
            fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bufIStream);
            document = new HWPFDocument(fileSystem);

            docRange = document.getRange();
            numParagraphs = docRange.numParagraphs();

            keySet = replacements.keySet();

            for(int i = 0; i < numParagraphs; i++) {
                paragraph = docRange.getParagraph(i);
                text = paragraph.text();

                numCharRuns = paragraph.numCharacterRuns();
                for(int j = 0; j < numCharRuns; j++) {
                    charRun = paragraph.getCharacterRun(j);

                    text = charRun.text();
                    keySetIterator = keySet.iterator();
                    while(keySetIterator.hasNext()) {

                        key = keySetIterator.next();
                        if(text.contains(key)) {

                            value = replacements.get(key);
                            int start = text.indexOf(key);
                            charRun.replaceText(key, value, start);


                            docRange = document.getRange();
                            paragraph = docRange.getParagraph(i);
                            charRun = paragraph.getCharacterRun(j);
                            text = charRun.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bufIStream.close();
            bufIStream = null;

            outputFile = new File(outputFilename);
            fileOStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            bufOStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOStream);
            document.write(bufOStream);
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught an: " + ex.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("Message: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Stacktrace follows.............");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        finally {
            if(bufIStream != null) {
                try {
                    bufIStream.close();
                    bufIStream = null;
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            if(bufOStream != null) {
                try {
                    bufOStream.flush();
                    bufOStream.close();
                    bufOStream = null;
                }
                catch(IOException ex) {

                }
            }
        }        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prueba replacer = new Prueba();

        HashMap<String, String> searchTerms = new HashMap<>();
        searchTerms.put("search term 1", "replacement term 1");
        searchTerms.put("search term 2", "replacement term 2");
        searchTerms.put("search term 3", "replacement term 3");
        searchTerms.put("search term 4", "replacement term 4");

        replacer.searchAndReplace("Document.doc", // Source Document
                "Replaced Document.doc", // Result Document
                searchTerms);                             // Search/replacement items
    }
}
```

When I execute my code, the error is the next:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/OldFileFormatException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at Prueba.searchAndReplace(Prueba.java:44)
    at Prueba.main(Prueba.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.OldFileFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the results are negative"? Do you get an error? If so, then what is exactly the error? Please explain in more detail what the actual problem is.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` - it looks like you are running the code with a different version of the POI library than what you compiled it with, or you are using wrong versions of other JAR files that the POI library depends on. Make sure you are using the right versions and that you have all the required JAR files.

Comment: You seem to be using different (older) POI jars at runtime. Make sure you don't have any duplicate POI jars on your classpath, make sure the jars you have are all of the same version, and try this [Apache POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) if you can't work out how

Comment: EEHHMMM, i use the lastest version (3.11), but this version not contain the POIFSFileSystem class .. so i import the library 3.0.2 and it have this class and i import this class with the library 3.0.2 ... Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you compile it and also run it with the same version - don't compile your code with one version and then run it with another version of POI.

Comment: POIFSFileSystem really is in 3.11 beta 2. There is no way that using jars from 3.0.2 and 3.11 at the same time will ever work!